# Apply a library function to multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete to build an autocomplete suggester, i've modified the code a bit so that instead of inputting the text like tags they can write full sentences with each item as suggestion for the next word

> he
>
> hello m
>
> hello my na
>
> hello my name

This is the code:

```
new Awesomplete('input[data-multiple]', {
list: ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "ari"],
filter: function (text, input) {
    return Awesomplete.FILTER_CONTAINS(text, input.match(/[^ ]*$/)[0]);
},

item: function (text, input) {
    return Awesomplete.ITEM(text, input.match(/[^,]*$/)[0]);
},

replace: function (text) {
    var before = this.input.value.match(/^.+ \s*|/)[0];
    this.input.value = before + text + " ";
}
});
```

Now this works but it only activates on the first input`input[data-multiple]`, whereas I have multiple inputs that I want to use the auto suggest on.

eg.

```html
<label>Name:</label>
<input data-multiple />

<label>Address:</label>
<input data-multiple />

<label>Mobile:</label>
<input data-multiple />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the library's constructor is using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), not [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Try manually query-selecting-all your elements. Then iterate over the node list and initialize the plugin for each entry in the node list.

Something like this:

```js
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-multiple]');

for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) { awesomizeInput(allInputs[i]) }

function awesomizeInput(input) {
  new Awesomplete(input, {
    list: ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "ari"],
    filter: function(text, input) {
      return Awesomplete.FILTER_CONTAINS(text, input.match(/[^ ]*$/)[0]);
    },
    item: function(text, input) {
      return Awesomplete.ITEM(text, input.match(/[^,]*$/)[0]);
    },
    replace: function(text) {
      var before = this.input.value.match(/^.+ \s*|/)[0];
      this.input.value = before + text + " ";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/awesomplete.js"></script>
<label>Name:</label>
<input data-multiple />

<label>Address:</label>
<input data-multiple />

<label>Mobile:</label>
<input data-multiple />
```